# url changer htaccess config

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am having a problem here, does anybody know How to change my url from

```
http://localhost/myProfile.php?id=1
```

to

```
http://localhost/myProfile/1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} myProfile\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myProfile/%1 [NC,L]
```

Note: The `[0-9]+` is a `regex` for accepting numbers between 0 and 9. The `+` means that there can be more than one of them. You can use another `regex` if you wish like `[A-F0-9]{32}` for example which accepts letters `A-F`, numbers `0-9` and there can be a total of 32 characters. You can tweek it to suit your needs. Keep in mind that if the conditions are not met the `RewriteRule` will not happen.

Comment: in fact sometimes it works but it doesnt get the css

Comment: What `CSS`? For `CSS` problems use `<base>` tag under the `<html>` tag. Check google for `base HTML tag` it will restore all the `CSS` links and everything should work.

Comment: @yllzon based on your example your `base` tag should look something like this:  `<base href="http://localhost" />`. Put that in your `HTML` document inside the `<head>` section. If you have problems ping me. Also, if my answer worked for you mark it as accepted please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ myprofile.php?user=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ myprofile.php?user=$1
```